# ¿Se puede utilizar Bootstrap en un formulario hecho con Razor en MVC?

Tags: bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Hice un formulario en una de las `View` de mi proyecto, y ahora quiero aplicarle Bootstrap para darle estilo, ¿es posible hacerlo?

Lo intenté de esta forma aunque sin resultados:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">

<label>Nombre</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NombreUsuario)
<br />

<label>Direccion</label><br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Direccion)
<br /> 

<label>Telefono</label><br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Telefono)
<br />

<label>Email</label><br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
<br />

</form>
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Pude hacerlo, y ahora quisiera usar la clase `form-horizontal` de Bootstrap. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Guardar", "Usuario", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IdUsuario)

    <label>Nombre</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NombreUsuario, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />

    <label>Contrasena</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Contrasena, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />

    <label>Direccion</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Direccion, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />

    <label>Telefono</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Telefono, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />

    <label>Email</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />

}
```

Agregándolo así `new {@class = "form-horizontal form-control"}` no funciona, y tampoco de este modo `<form class = "form-horizontal"></form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sí es posible, si te refieres a agregar estilos prueba con esto:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NombreUsuario, new { @class = "AquiElEstiloQueDeseasAgregar" })
```

**Editada**

Agregando estilos a tu formulario:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Guardar", "Usuario", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona bien al agregar `@class = "form-control"` pero no con el `form-horizontal`, alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: de nada, podrías agregar el código de la vista por favor?

Comment: muy bien, ya esta puesto el código :)

Comment: acabo de editar la respuesta, espero sea lo estas buscando! Una recomendación para el desarrollo web es que te hagas buen amigo de las "Developer Tools" presionando F12 en Firefox, Opera, IE/Edge, Google Chrome, ve inspeccionando elementos, jugando con las propiedades de los CSS, clickeando en los checkboxes solo por ver que hacen! Hay tanto por aprender! Lo bonito de esta industria es que la unión hace mejor software. Sigue adelante con todo el power!